# how to hide and show in react on particular conditions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

currently I am working on **React/Redux** and my project is an e-commerce application, There are two types of payments methods i.e. cash and card payments, Now two payments methods are shown in my Product display page i.e cash and card payments, i want to make a functionality in which I can hide cash icon if the product price is greater than 10,000, payment methods icon are coming from **static CSS sprite**, can anyone help me to achieve this functionality, thanks in advance, my product display page and my react code is display below

---

```
case 'warrantyAndPaymentMethods':
                /* WARRANTY/PAYMENT METHODS */
                subComponent = (
                    <div className={styles.warrantyPaymentCtr}>
                        {offer &&
                            offer.warranty &&
                            <div className={styles.warrantyCtr}>
                                <p className={styles.label}>
                                    {I18n.getText('product.warranty', {}, 'Warranty')}
                                </p>
                                <p className={styles.warrantyDescription}>
                                    {offer.warranty}
                                </p>
                            </div>}

                        {/* PAYMENT METHODS START */}
                        <div className={styles.paymentCtr}>
                            <p className={styles.label}>
                                {I18n.getText('product.payment', {}, 'Payment')}
                            </p>
                            {/* PAYMENT METHODS */}
                            <ul className="paymentMethods">
                                <li className="cash">Cash</li>
                                <li className="visa">Visa</li>
                                <li className="mastercard">Mastercard</li>
                                <li className="amex">American Express</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        {/* PAYMENT METHODS END */}
                    </div>
                );
```

[image]

Comment: Do u know how to trigger a state change of a component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same with other elements:

```
                        {/* PAYMENT METHODS */}
                        <ul className="paymentMethods">
                            {price <= 10000 && <li className="cash">Cash</li>}
                            <li className="visa">Visa</li>
                            <li className="mastercard">Mastercard</li>
                            <li className="amex">American Express</li>
                        </ul>
```

Note that you need the `price` variable to have the current price (or use some other variable that contains that value).